# How to open a resource file in a WAR using a string pathname?

Tags: java, spring, file-io, war, ear

I am building a WAR/EAR and one of my components reads in many custom configuration files using File IO:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

The **path** above is a String that is passed as a property to this class through Spring's **applicationContext.xml** file.

What String path do I specify if I want to put all these configuration files inside a WAR? Can this even be done? Or is the component incorrect and should be using `getResourceAsStream()` instead?

I browsed around and found a lot of info on `getResource()` and *URI*. However, I could not find whether it is possible to create the right file path to a resource inside **applicationContext.xml**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In spring environment it's better to use [spring resources API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)
Simple example:

```
@Inject
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public void someMethod() {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:my-file.xml");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = resource.getInputStream();
        // do work
        ....
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuetly(is);
    }
}
```

If you want to access external files (non-classpath resources, which should be located in META-INF/resources within the archive) with non fixed paths you should put such paths in main properties file and load it on app deploy.

edit: change @Resource to @Inject in example

Answer (score 2):

The key to accessing files is to make them available in your classpath. By default in a WAR file all the files under WEB-INF/classes are added to the classpath and you can reference those files.

For example: lets assume this is your WAR file structure

```
webapp.war
 |
 |---> WEB-INF
 |------|
 |      |----> classes
 |              |----> MyResource.properties
 |---> index.html
 |---> images
 |-------|
 |       ----> logo.gif
```

You can access your "MyResource.properties" using the following API

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyResource.properties"));
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Having file resources within your classpath eases the access. But there's another possibility, like described in the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618483/relative-views-in-view-states-within-a-flow-that-is-loaded-from-a-jar-file). The [servlet API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) describes where such resources should be located. Basically your WAR should contain a folder **META-INF/resources**, where your files, that should not be in the classpath, have to be placed.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. I get an `IOException` because the file can't be found. Also, I saw the following comment, "By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked." at [java.io.File javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: According to spring you need to specify the resource using "classpath:MyResource.properties". You  can find the reference here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/resources.html