# Can I reference a file from within a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xlsx

I am currently writing a spring boot program that should populate an XLSX template with data and am trying to read the template from inside the project.  My directory structure is as follows:

[image]

I am now trying to access the file using the following code:

```
try {
        InputStream fis = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xlstemplates/billingReview.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook billingReviewTemplate = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Unfortunately I have yet to find a way to read the xlsx file into an InputStream.  It always comes back null.  Anyone have any pointers on how I can reference that file that is included in the project?

Comment: For starters your path is wrong it is `static/clstemplates/billingReview.xls`. Instead of trying to load it yourself I suggest the spring Resource abstraction, use `new ClassPathResource("static/xlstemplates/billingReview.xls")` instead of what you have now. And I would actually suggest to use neither and use the Spring `AbstractXlsxView` and implement/override the `createWorkbook` method and then create your view class.

Comment: Answered already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775363/how-to-open-a-resource-file-in-a-war-using-a-string-pathname